# How to disable a contextmenu for a panel

Tags: c#

I have two panels - panel1 and panel2

I want my context menu to only work for panel1 but not panel2.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the panel's context menu to null

```
panel1.ContextMenu = null;
```

if you want to a panel that have context menu, you should set your context menu to that panel . so if you don't want the context menu on that panel,  **just don't set it**.

Comment: @user1667459 did you set the context menu to that panel before? if yes, don't set it. if no , there must don't be any context menu on your panel.   write the code on constructor or form_load event .

Comment: okay this is what im trying to use 

`panel1.ContextMenu = contextMenuStrip1;
   panel2.ContextMenu = null;
   panel3.ContextMenu = null;`

the first line doesn't work though.

Comment: yeah,so do you get context menu on the panel 2 & 3 again? if you didn't set the context menu before, the panel2.ContextMenu is null by default.

Comment: `this.panel1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;`